# Error bash: syntax error near unexpected toekn 'do' compiling tables

Tags: mysql, bash

currently using the following guide to create a private server

http://arcemuwiki.blogspot.dk/2012/10/contents-how-to-compile-arcemu-with.html

I get to this step in the guide and when i run:

```
for table in $(mysql -u root --password=mypass mydb -e "show tables;"); do mysql -u root --password=mypass mydb -e "DROP TABLE $table;"; done;
```

I get the error:

> Error bash: syntax error near unexpected toekn 'do' compiling tables

I have not been able to solve this :/ all help will be appreciated.

Creating the arc_logon, arc_characters and arc_world database structure
Return now to the Arcemu code directory where the base SQL structure files are located.

```
cd /home/arcemu/src/code/sql


ubuntu@ubuntu:/home/arcemu/src/code/sql$ ls -l
total 480
-rw-r--r-- 1 arcemu arcemu   2146 2011-05-12 22:03 2834_logon_structure.sql
-rw-r--r-- 1 arcemu arcemu  36315 2011-05-12 22:03 3800_character_structure.sql
-rw-r--r-- 1 arcemu arcemu 421549 2011-05-12 22:03 3955_world_structure.sql
drwxr-xr-x 3 arcemu arcemu   4096 2011-05-12 22:03 character_updates
drwxr-xr-x 3 arcemu arcemu   4096 2011-05-12 22:03 extra_scripts
drwxr-xr-x 3 arcemu arcemu   4096 2011-05-12 22:03 logon_updates
drwxr-xr-x 3 arcemu arcemu   4096 2011-05-12 22:03 misc
drwxr-xr-x 4 arcemu arcemu   4096 2011-05-12 22:03 utilities
drwxr-xr-x 3 arcemu arcemu   4096 2011-05-12 22:03 world_updates
ubuntu@ubuntu:/home/arcemu/src/code/sql$
```

**NOTE** 
In order to drop all of the tables in the database (clear all db), use the following CLI command. WARNING! This will delete your entire database!

```
for table in $(mysql -u root --password=mypass mydb -e "show tables;"); do mysql -u root --password=mypass mydb -e "DROP TABLE $table;"; done;
```

Alright nevermind, i solved this problem; however, now I am getting an sql error where it says: 
    ERROR 1049 (42000): Uknown database 'mydb'

I think where my confusion lies is that in the guide it has me create 3 databases: arc_logon, arc_characters, and arc_world.

Then it has me just the files in the sql folder and I really dont understand what I am trying to do with this for loop. Previously I had believed it was just a note and tried to go to the next step.

The next step is as follows:
    Add a users to the arc_logon
    Before any users can enter the game, they must have a username and password. The user    privileges can be specified (user, GM, etc).
    First, add the admin account; 
    mysql -u root -p arc_logon
    type the following.... INSERT INTO `accounts` (login, password, gm, flags, banned)  VALUES ('your-login-name', 'your-password', 'az', '24', '0');

However, when i try to to INSERT INTO line, i get the error that there is not table called accounts; therefore, I was assuming I had to create the table using this for loop for some reason.

Comment: Are you actually running that as a single line like that or did you put it in a script file on multiple lines? If multiple lines in a file does the file has DOS line-endings?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using `mysqladmin drop mydb`? That would drop all the tables (and routines and triggers and views too).

Comment: I am running this in the command line as one line and when I use mysqladmin to drop the db I just remove them when I want to creates an accounts table using the files in the sql folder

Comment: Really....if I remove all tables from these databases....or I don't remove all of the tables....I still don't have a table called accounts in my arc_log on db thus I am confused on how to get this to set up correctly?.....when I create a database does that table populate itself or does the command line Insert Into create a table named accounts because I don't think this occurs since I get an error saying accounts table dne